# Decoding Spring security BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring-security, decode, bcrypt, password-encryption

Is it possible using Spring Security or other library decode encoded password by BCryptPasswordEncoder?

Comment: No. It is not. That is the point.

Comment: Well how integrate StandardPBEStringEncryptor in SpringSecurity (for example)?

Comment: I sure hope it's not possible..

Comment: @Kayaman you and me both...

Comment: So if I use Spring Security, there is no way restore raw password once encoded?

Comment: @zzheads if there was then the _entire point_ of **one way** hashing would sort of be violated, no? The whole idea is that if your password database is compromised then no one can ever recover the original passwords. Hashing is a many to one function, so many (a theoretical infinity) of values hash to the same output. If you were to find one of those values then this would be a [pre-image attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` works on one way hashing principle that can be only used for encoding, there is no way to decode the password encoded by `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.
You can only match the encoded password with the raw password.